# Adding data from foreach onto existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently creating an array like so

```
$propertyData[] = array(
    'propertyID' => $property->propertyID,
    'propertyDepartment' => $property->department,
    'displayAddress' => $property->propertyAddress->displayAddress,
    'price' => $property->propertyDetails->price
);
```

I then have a one to many on one of my models, as such, I am adding multiple additional data like so

```
foreach ($property->propertyImages as $image) {
    $propertyData[]['images'] = array(
        'imageUrl' => $image->imageUrl,
    );
}
```

The result of the above is something like the following

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "propertyID" => "Some Data"
    "propertyDepartment" => "Some Data"
    "displayAddress" => "Some Data"
    "price" => "111111"
  ]
  "images" => array:3 [
    0 => array:1 [
      "imageUrl" => "Some URL"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
      "imageUrl" => "Some URL"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [
      "imageUrl" => "Some URL"
    ]
  ]
]
```

This is nearly what I am after, but not quite.  I want the images element to be part of the original array.  So what I am after is the following

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "propertyID" => "Some Data"
    "propertyDepartment" => "Some Data"
    "displayAddress" => "Some Data"
    "price" => "111111"
    "images" => array:3 [
        0 => array:1 [
          "imageUrl" => "Some URL"
        ]
        1 => array:1 [
          "imageUrl" => "Some URL"
        ]
        2 => array:1 [
          "imageUrl" => "Some URL"
        ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: can you specify your problem more  clearly? i mean what is the problem now?

Comment: A quick question, do you first fill the entire array with properties and then add the images or do you first add a property and then add the images relative to that property?

Comment: I query the database for a property based on an ID.  That property can have many images.

Comment: Is `$property->propertyImages` already an array?  Could you not just assign it like `'images' => $property->propertyImages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "propertyID" => "Some Data"
    "propertyDepartment" => "Some Data"
    "displayAddress" => "Some Data"
    "price" => "111111"
    "images" => array:3 [
        "Some URL",
        "Some URL",
        "Some URL"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

So, first created an `$images` variable with array of images:

```
$images = [];
foreach ($property->propertyImages as $image) {
  $images[] = $image->imageUrl;
}
```

And after that create your array with all properties:

```
$propertyData[] = array(
  'propertyID' => $property->propertyID,
  'propertyDepartment' => $property->department,
  'displayAddress' => $property->propertyAddress->displayAddress,
  'price' => $property->propertyDetails->price,
  'images' => $images
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so basically the problem you are having here is that you are automatically assigning a new element to an array and afterwards you don't know which is the index that the element was stored at. The easiest way I think you could do this is the following:

```php
// First create a separate array for the property
// Notice I am adding an empty images array here
$newProperty = array(
    'propertyID' => $property->propertyID,
    'propertyDepartment' => $property->department,
    'displayAddress' => $property->propertyAddress->displayAddress,
    'price' => $property->propertyDetails->price,
    'images' => array()
);

// Then with your foreach you can easily add images to the images array
foreach ($property->propertyImages as $image) {
    $newProperty['images'][]['imageUrl'] = $image->imageUrl
}

// And finally you add the new property to your final array

$propertyData[] = $newProperty;
```

Personally I would do the following for the image insertion

```php
foreach ($property->propertyImages as $image) {
    array_push($newProperty['images'], $image);
    // This way I'd have all the info related to the image
}
```

That should solve your problem.